# python multithreaded server

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

What I'm trying to program is a simple multithreaded python game server for fun. After much frustration, I've not been able to figure out why my test client connection times out. Here's my server.py code:

```
import socket
import threading
import clientThread
import struct
import string


class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.HOST = 'localhost'
        self.PORT = 22085
        self.BUFFIZE = 1024
        self.ADDRESS = (self.HOST,self.PORT)
        self.clientList = []
        input("Press enter to start the server. . .")
        self.running = True
        self.serverSock = socket.socket()
        self.serverSock.bind(self.ADDRESS)
        self.serverSock.listen(2)
        self.clientThread = clientThread.clientThread(self)
        print("Starting client thread. . .")
        self.clientThreadObj = threading.Thread(target = self.clientThread.start, args = (self))
        print("Awaiting connections. . .")
        while self.running:
            clientInfo = self.serverSock.accept()
            print("Client connected from %s." % clientInfo[1])
            # Append to clientThread list...

        self.serverSock.close()
        print("- end -")


serv = Server()
```

The server starts the thread for existing connections and starts listening. The thread built for existing connections, `clientThread`, loops through a list of client objects which for now do nothing, they are simply architectural. Here is the clientThread.py

```
import socket
import threading
import struct
import string


class clientThread:
    def __init__(self, serv):
        self.server = serv
        self.clientList = []
        self.running = True
        print("Client thread created. . .")
    def start(self):
        print("Beginning client thread loop. . .")
        while self.running:
            for client in self.clientList:
                message = client.sock.recv(self.server.BUFFSIZE)
                if message != None and message != "":
                    client.update(message)
```

And finally, the very simple client object:

```
import string


class clientObject:
    def start(self,clientInfo):
        self.sock = clientInfo[0]
        self.address = clientInfo[1]
    def update(self,message):
        self.sock.send("Testamundo.\r\n".encode())
```

Now, the problem here is that my client can't even connect to my server. It simply times out. Here is the code for my simple client test:

```
import socket
import string

address = ("192.168.1.1",22085)
mySocket = socket.socket()

mySocket.connect(address)
print("Connected successfully!")
```

This returns on the line that connects to address, "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

Any suggestions? Thanks! Sorry for all this code, I wasn't sure if I needed to post it all or not, so I figured it couldn't hurt too much.

Comment: You might be reinventing the wheel. Check out http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html More specifically the section on the multithreading mixins http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html#asynchronous-mixins

Comment: @Novikov How did that module escape me! I didn't even know it existed... Thanks!

Comment: @Novikov: That should be an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have two systems?  Does the server system have an IP of 192.168.1.1?  If you only have one system, the localhost address is 127.0.0.1.  That was the first change I had to make to your code to get a connection when running the server and client on the same system.

Another issue is your client thread doesn't actually start.  Since you want a client thread class, here's how to declare and start it:

1. Subclass from threading.Thread.
2. Override `__init__` for your behavior, but call `__init__` in the base class first.
3. Override `run` for the thread work.
4. Create an instance and call its `start` method.

Another problem is `recv` blocks if the client hasn't sent any data, so if you try to connect multiple clients it will hang in your loop over the client list.  You'll need a thread per client or use `select.select` to query the client sockets for read/write readiness.

Below is the changed code that got a single client to respond, but it needs work to handle multiple clients.  It also needs to set up a protocol to handle messages.  TCP is a streaming protocol (no message boundaries), so a send of 'abc' and '123' could result in a receive of 'abc123' or 'ab' and 'c123', etc.  It'll have to handle closing the connections and remove the client objects from the client list as well.

Good luck!  You'll learn a lot figuring out how to do all this from scratch.  Look at the `socketserver.py` library as well for example code.

#### srv.py

```
import socket
import threading
import struct
import string

class clientThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, serv):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.server = serv
        self.clientList = []
        self.running = True
        print("Client thread created. . .")
    def run(self):
        print("Beginning client thread loop. . .")
        while self.running:
            for client in self.clientList:
                message = client.sock.recv(self.server.BUFFSIZE)
                if message != None and message != "":
                    client.update(message)

class clientObject(object):
    def __init__(self,clientInfo):
        self.sock = clientInfo[0]
        self.address = clientInfo[1]
    def update(self,message):
        self.sock.send("Testamundo.\r\n".encode())

class Server(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.HOST = 'localhost'
        self.PORT = 22085
        self.BUFFSIZE = 1024
        self.ADDRESS = (self.HOST,self.PORT)
        self.clientList = []
        input("Press enter to start the server. . .")
        self.running = True
        self.serverSock = socket.socket()
        self.serverSock.bind(self.ADDRESS)
        self.serverSock.listen(2)
        self.clientThread = clientThread(self)
        print("Starting client thread. . .")
        self.clientThread.start()
        print("Awaiting connections. . .")
        while self.running:
            clientInfo = self.serverSock.accept()
            print("Client connected from {}.".format(clientInfo[1]))
            self.clientThread.clientList.append(clientObject(clientInfo))

        self.serverSock.close()
        print("- end -")

serv = Server()
```

#### clnt.py

```
import socket
import string

address = ('localhost',22085)
mySocket = socket.socket()

mySocket.connect(address)
print("Connected successfully!")
mySocket.send('blah'.encode())
print(mySocket.recv(1024))
```

#### Output (srv.py)

```
Press enter to start the server. . .
Client thread created. . .
Starting client thread. . .
Beginning client thread loop. . .
Awaiting connections. . .
Client connected from ('127.0.0.1', 52850).
```

#### Output (clnt.py)

```
Connected successfully!
b'Testamundo.\r\n'
```